# What is the maximum number of triangles in d-regular graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I tried to search the literature, but I was unsuccessful. I know that in general, there can be as much as $O(n^3)$ (or $O(m^{3/2})$) triangles. But is there a bound that uses maximum degree of the graph? In particular, I am interested in $d$-regular graphs, and I am looking for asymptotic bound $O(f(d,n))$, where $n$ is the number of vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each vertex can be involved in at most $\binom{d}{2}$ different triangles, so it should be $O(d^2 n)$ triangles.

Comment: And this is tight: taking a graph consisting of $\frac{n}{d+1}$ disjoint copies of $K_{d+1}$ achieves the theoretical maximum of $\frac13 n \binom d2$.